# How to use BLoC in a login page

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I have a login page ,contains two TextFormField.
How can i use BLoC to matain these two TextFormField text,and when i press login button,I can get these two TextFormField at the same time

ps: I want to put login form in a single file.

I have konw how to matain one state in a BLoC , e.g a count state, through a sink to add ,and a stream to rerender. How about two state in a BLoC

Can anyboday give me some tips, thanks

Comment: Here you go: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-a-simple-login-form-in-flutter-using-bloc-pattern-b55ad52a2a10

Comment: try to use combineLatest2. It merges the given Streams into one Observable sequence by using the [combiner] function whenever any of the observable sequences emits an item.

The Observable will not emit until all streams have emitted at least one item. 

example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55951673/1723187

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this  https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=setup 
Step by step to create a Login Form with package `flutter_bloc`

code snippet for Login Form

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login/login/login.dart';

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<LoginForm> createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _onLoginButtonPressed() {
      BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(
        LoginButtonPressed(
          username: _usernameController.text,
          password: _passwordController.text,
        ),
      );
    }

    return BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is LoginFailure) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('${state.error}'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'username'),
                  controller: _usernameController,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'password'),
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed:
                      state is! LoginLoading ? _onLoginButtonPressed : null,
                  child: Text('Login'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: state is LoginLoading
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : null,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]